# How to move mysql.socket into postfix chroot

Tags: mysql, postfix, chroot

I want `postfix` to be able to talk to `mysql`, without letting it out of its `chroot`.

I guessed that moving the socket-file in to the `chroot`, should solve it, but that wasn't as easy.

If i try to update all references I can find of `/var/run/mysqld` to  `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/mysqld`.

Mysql want start, and ask me to run `systemctl status mysql.service`, then I get:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
        Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
        Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since tis 2016-09-06 08:46:34 CEST; 7s ago
       Process: 2747 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
       Process: 2743 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Main PID: 2747 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);
              : 2748 (mysql-systemd-s)
        CGroup:   /system.slice/mysql.service  
           └─control  
             ├─2748 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post  
             └─2790 sleep 1  

sep 06 08:46:34 kglive systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...   
sep 06 08:46:36 kglive systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

and `grep ERROR /var/log/mysql/error.log` repeats:

```
2016-09-06T06:41:24.615150Z 0 [ERROR] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/spool/postfix/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.
2016-09-06T06:41:24.615154Z 0 [ERROR] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
2016-09-06T06:41:24.615158Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Currently, I use a manual mount-bind between the dirs, but I have to redo it after each reboot, using `ln -s /var/spool/postfix/var/run/mysqld /var/run/mysqld` or putting the-mount in `/etc/fstab` didn't help, I guess its because starting mysqld recreated the `/var/run/mysqld` folder when its starts.

- Is it possible to move the socket-file?
- What other options are available?

(I know about letting postfix out of chroot, but I hope I don't have to)
I think the mount-bind solution stops working on a `service mysql restart`.